# Pass data from NSViewController to another NSViewController which is in NSSplitViewController?

Tags: swift, macos, nsviewcontroller

Hello i've got problems to send data to NSSplitViewController. It doesn't seems work like in IOS development.

firstController:

```
class LoginController: NSViewController {
 //.....
  @IBAction func Login(_ sender: Any) {
     //....
     let story = NSStoryboard(name: NSStoryboard.Name(rawValue: "Main"), 
                bundle: nil).instantiateController(withIdentifier: 
                NSStoryboard.SceneIdentifier(rawValue: "SPLIT")) as! 
                NSSplitViewController
      let vc : ContainerController = ContainerController();
      vc.passedData = "karosas";
      self.view.window?.contentViewController = story;
     //....
   }
 //.....
}
```

second NSSplitViewController :

```
import Cocoa

class ContainerController: NSSplitViewController {

    var passedData = "";

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        print(passedData);
        print("nzn");
    }

}
```

Now i'm trying to send data to NSViewSplitController. I need to pass data to NSViewController which is in NSSplitViewController. I did try many different ways, but i failed. So i thought that i need to pass data first to SplitController and then to ViewController. But i can't even send any data to NSSplitViewController. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 2):

If the LoginController and the MenuController are both in the ContainerController, you could do something like:

LoginController

```
import Cocoa

class LoginController: NSViewController {
 //.....
  @IBAction func Login(_ sender: Any) {
     //....
     self.userName = value["name"] as! String
     let MenuVC = parent?.childViewControllers[1] as! MenuController // 0 or 1 depending on order in SplitView
      MenuVC.passedData = self.username
      self.view.window?.contentViewController = parent as! ContainerController
     //....
   }
 //.....
}
```

MenuController

```
import Cocoa

class MenuController: NSViewController {

    var passedData = ""

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        print(passedData)
        print("nzn")
    }

}
```

Comment: This works perfectly for SplitViewController, you need to create new NSSplitViewController file called ContainerController. It's also worth mentioning the leftmost view controller is childViewController[0] and the rightmost controller is childViewController[n - 1]

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to do that using this code.

```
        self.userName = value["name"] as! String;
        let story = NSStoryboard(name: NSStoryboard.Name(rawValue: "Main"), bundle: nil)
        .instantiateController(withIdentifier: NSStoryboard.SceneIdentifier(rawValue: "SPLIT")) 
        as! ContainerController
        let dest = story.childViewControllers[0] as! MenuController;
        dest.passData = self.userName;
        self.view.window?.contentViewController = story;
```

I dont know is that a good approach, but it works.